# Python : Module not found

Tags: python, windows

When I use pip freeze command, it returns

```
C:\Users\Keshav Reddy>pip freeze
Warning: cannot find svn location for guippy===0.1.5dev-r0
beautifulsoup4==4.4.1
future==0.15.2
## FIXME: could not find svn URL in dependency_links for this package:
guippy===0.1.5dev-r0
keyboard==0.6.5
Pillow==3.1.1
PyAutoGUI==0.9.33
PyMsgBox==1.0.3
pypiwin32==219
PyScreeze==0.1.8
python-subprocess2==0.2.1
PyTweening==1.0.3
pywinauto==0.5.4
requests==2.9.1
robotframework==3.0
SimplePool==0.1
urlopen==1.0.0
virtualenv==14.0.6
```

but I couldn't import any of these modules.

```
C:\Users\Keshav Reddy>python
Python 3.5.1 (v3.5.1:37a07cee5969, Dec  6 2015, 01:38:48) [MSC v.1900 32 bit           (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pyautogui
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'pyautogui'
```

How can I import these modules?

Comment: Simple web search: http://pyautogui.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html

Answer (score 0):

Begin by installing a release of 'guippy' module.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried downloading Anaconda? It helps alot with downloading modules.